# Print current residual from callback in scipy.sparse.linalg.cg

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra

I am using `scipy.sparse.linalg.cg` to solve a large, sparse linear system, and it works fine, except that I would like to add a progress report, so that I can monitor the residual as the solver works. I've managed to set up a callback, but I can't figure out how to access the current residual from inside the callback. Calculating the residual myself is possible, of course, but that is a rather heavy operation, which I'd like to avoid. Have I missed something, or is there no efficient way of getting at the residual?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The callback is only sent `xk`, the current solution vector. So you don't have direct access to the residual. However, the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.11.0/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative.py#L240) shows `resid` is a local variable in the `cg` function.

So, with CPython, it is possible to use the `inspect` module to peek at the local variables in the caller's frame:

```
import inspect
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg as splinalg
import random

def report(xk):
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    print(frame.f_locals['resid'])

N = 200
A = sparse.lil_matrix( (N, N) )
for _ in xrange(N):
    A[random.randint(0, N-1), random.randint(0, N-1)] = random.randint(1, 100)

b = np.random.randint(0, N-1, size = N)
x, info = splinalg.cg(A, b, callback = report)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Strange that a hack like this is needed, though. Accessing the residual is the single most common thing to do in a CG callback.

Answer (score 0):

As [answered previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14243877/16627888), you can use the callback function to access the variables inside cg call. I combine this with the outer naming scope to track some metrics of the iterative method. Here is how you can compute the l2 norm of the residue, for example:

```py
    # Solving a linear system Au = b
    # Here, the result of Au is given by a function called `laplacian_operator`

    matrix = scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator(
        (num_points, num_points), matvec=laplacian_operator
    )

    residuals = []  # here is where you will store the metrics

    def report_callback(sol_vec):
        # notice that `matrix`, `b` and `residuals` come from the outer scope
        relative_residual_norm = np.linalg.norm(b - matrix * sol_vec) / np.linalg.norm(b)
        residuals.append(relative_residual_norm)

    u, cg_info = scipy.sparse.linalg.cg(matrix, b, callback=report_callback)
```

Notice that in this approach you need to re-evaluate the product Ax at every iteration, but it is less hack-y than accessing the internal variables with `inspect`.